# Use IIS as an internet file server for our local AD network

Tags: active-directory, iis, file-server

I have a Windows specific question.  Some of our staff have approached me asking if its possible to have a web portal setup where they can access our entire local network's active directory folders.  So that they can get access to files if they are working from home for the day.

My immediate response was no - as while I'm sure I could hack something together with code; this needs to be robust as sensitive information exists on our AD network.  My thoughts were that remote desktop could serve this purpose just as well - and is proven in the enterprise world.

Thinking about it more though; a web portal would be convenient & really when you consider that you have to open up ports (manually for each person that requests RDP access) in our firewall for remote desktop - then really is it at all any more secure than a web server running SSL?  That of course is assuming that there is a robust solution that exists already; I don't want to roll my own & google searches for this sort of thing haven't yielded a silver bullet.

Our local AD server is running Windows Server 2012 and here are the requirements:
1) Remote user visits public web domain e.g. ournetwork.ourcompany.com (we have a static ip)
2) User logs on using their usual AD login credentials
3) User is presented with a web based folder structure they can browse to upload / download files (assuming their AD creds have the perms for that folder)

Does something like this exist already?
Thanks!

Comment: SharePoint.....

Comment: good point; for some reason I wasn't thinking along those lines - was hoping for something a little less involved and more single purpose.  More of a linux guy myself - so perhaps share point is the simple answer to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint can be a portal to anything but is not simple, requires an administrator and possibly a developer to be successful.

WebDAV is a web server. Can be attached as a drive (with some scripting or documentation) to enable upload.

File sync solutions exist, including Offline Availability in Windows, or your choice of cloud shared storage products. These may not be the web interface and full access to the shares that you asked for, but are suited for offline work.

Comment: Thanks - this is more aligned with what I was looking for; at a glance it should work well.